# How to install specific package version when it's defined by 2 different PPAs?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, software-sources, bitcoin

I want to install luke-dash-jr's BIP148 bitcoin PPA which can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/~luke-jr/+archive/ubuntu/bitcoin-core-bip148-unofficial-builds).

I've already added the unofficial Bitcoin PPA to my `sources.list`; that PPA can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/ubuntu/bitcoin).

Both PPAs define a `bitcoin` package. How do I install just Luke's for the time being?

I realize I can just remove the unofficial Bitcoin PPA from `sources.list` but was wondering if there's a different solution.

Comment: you can use aptitude or specify the version with apt-get

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/124174/how-can-i-specify-the-repository-from-which-a-package-will-be-installed-emacs